# Azure running triggered webjob won't update after continuous deployment

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have a .NET triggered webjob running in a .NET Azure website. I have continuous deployment set up using Azure DevOps. Is there a way to update a running triggered webjob to the latest version automatically, i.e. when I push a commit? The website redeploys automatically upon commit, which is good, but not the webjob. Currently, it seems I have to delete the webjob in the portal, redeploy the site, then manually trigger the webjob in the portal again.

Answer (score 0):

If your project's fold structure is the same as Azure Webjobs (App_Data\jobs\triggered\YourProjects), you can choose Local Git in Deployment Cental to redeploy your webjob automatically:[Deployment Cental](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQxb4.png)
And you can find details in: [Continuous Delivery of Azure WebJobs via Git](https://janatdevelopment.com/2015/12/04/continuous-delivery-of-azure-webjobs-via-git/)